# syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in yii1

Tags: php, yii, syntax-error

`syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)` in yii1 framework i want to add class for form tag when i keep htmloptions it shows errors.

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
        'method'=>'get',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'form-inline'),
));
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'title',array('class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'title')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,title); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'functional_area', CHtml::listData(FunctionalArea::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'functional_area'), array('empty' => 'Functional Area','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,functional_area); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'state',array('class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'state')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,state); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'experience_min', range(0,50), array('empty' => 'Select','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,experience_min); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'experience_max', range(0,50), array('empty' => 'Select','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,experience_max); ?>
        </div>

        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search',array('class'=>'red_btn')); ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="Jobs[user_id]" value="<?php echo $user_id;?>" />

        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `)` after `'method'=>'get',`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello rockstar and welcome to the Stackoverflow.

You have made a mistake in your parenthesis. Change your code part above to the following:

```
<?php 
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
     'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
     'method' => 'get',
     'htmlOptions' => array(
         'class' => 'form-inline'
      )
));
?>
```

Comment: Great it worked i  am new to yii1 so i don't  know how its.

Comment: It's actually more about array definition in PHP. Read some articles about arrrays, multidimensional arrays and have fun :)